# jquery-sortable - how to get the value of parent and child alternatively like (Title1_orange, Title1_pink...)?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

when i sorting the child, I have got value of parent and child but it will comes like (title1orangepinkyellowgreen, title1orangepinkyellowgreen, title1orangepinkyellowgreen, title1orangepinkyellowgreen), but i have to print it like this way (Title1_orange, title_pink...)

```
var addPositions = function() {
    $('.droptrue, .droptrue1').each(function() {
        var position = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            $(this).data('position', position);
            position++;
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
var  treeList = "";
treeList = "<ul id=\"createTree\" class=\"droptrue1 mt1\">";
for(var key in jsonObj){
  //alert("key: " + key + ", value: " + jsonObj[key])
    for (var skey in jsonObj[key]) {
        treeList +=  ("<li class=\"listTree\" id=\"asdf\">"+skey +"<ul class=\"droptrue mt\">");
        for (var sskey in jsonObj[key][skey]){
            for (var ssskey in jsonObj[key][skey][sskey]){
                treeList +=  ("<li class=\"innerList\">"+jsonObj[key][skey][sskey][ssskey]+"</li>");
            }
        }       
        treeList +=  "</ul></li>";
    }
}
treeList += "</ul>";
$('#tree').append(treeList); 
addPositions();
$(".droptrue").sortable({
      connectWith: "ul.mt",
      dropOnEmpty: true,
      stop: function(event, ui) {
         var order = [];
         ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
         order.push($(this).data('position'));
         var c = $(this).text();    
         var z = $(this).parents().eq(1).text();
         alert(z);
         $("#cl").append(z+"<br />");
       });
     }
  });
```

Here fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/VKWeC/

Thanks

Comment: I can tell you why it's doing that. It's going up to the parent li item. The li item though has that list inside of it. So it will include everything. Can you create a span there or something, that way you can go up to that span only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i suggested above, maybe try to add a span since that title is basically the lists sibling "ul" portion.

http://jsfiddle.net/VKWeC/1/

You can also use prev() instead of siblings. It really depends how complicated your html is going to hey. There is also find().

http://jsfiddle.net/VKWeC/2/